# App association in Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile

How can I select a different app for viewing photos when a photo is tapped in file explorer, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that from File Manager, but you can do that from **photos** app.

Select the image and press **Edit** , You'll get several apps to open the image with, for Eg; Lumia selfie, PicsaArt, Pixlr, etc.

Comment: He is asking how to chaange the default app associated with a filetype i.e) the app which will be opened when a paticular type of file is clicked in email, one drive, filee manager, etc.... Your answer does not provide a solution.

Comment: Well, we can't do that, You know that, right?

Comment: Then your answer must indicate that in the first place and clearly indicate that there is no possible way. Any alternate workarounds can be added after that.

Comment: @Kolappan, Ram said "you can't do that from File Manager" what is unclear here?

Comment: @GlacialMan The OP asks for selecting a different app for viewing photos. He wants to select an app which opens phtos from File manager, whatsapp, email, onedrive, etc... **File manager is just an example** (the question itself says it as an example). I have asked this in my first comment. *Cannot be done from file manager* is not the same as *cannot be done at all*. I understand Ram's answer perfectly. I just want to improve it so that others can understand it well too. I hope this clarifies your doubt regarding my comments.